# Ruby: Private method called for 3:Fixnum

Tags: ruby, split, nomethoderror, fixnum

I am trying to learn the nuances of this simple function but am not sure what I need to do to fix this NoMethodError. How do I make 'split' public rather than private? Will that fix the problem?

Here is my code:

```
DATA = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
DATA.each do |line|
vals = line.split
print vals[0] + vals[1], " "
end
```

Here is the error message I get when I run this in IRB:

```
NoMethodError: private method `split' called for 3:Fixnum
```

Comment: Why are you trying to split a number in the first place?

Comment: What you have in that list named DATA are numbers of type FIXNUM. and there is no split method there!

Comment: Please describe what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: thanks guys, next time I will be sure to post what I'm trying to accomplish so it is more clear! Now I know that split is for strings not integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the method `split` on a number object — this method exists in the `String` class but not in `Fixnum`.

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
DATA = ['3,4', '5,6', '7,8']
DATA.each do |val|
  vals = line.split ','
  print vals[0] + vals[1], " "
end
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear what you are trying to do. You don't have a "line", you have an element from the *Array* that is an *Integer* value. `Split` is a method defined on `String.`

```
DATA = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
DATA.each do |val|
  print val
end
```

Now, the reason you get that confusing error message is a little bit interesting. As it happens, there is a `Kernel#split` which allows a Perl-like brevity for scripts. It splits the global variable `$_` which holds the last result from `gets`.

```
>> gets
how now brown cow
=> "how now brown cow\n"
>> split ' '
=> ["how", "now", "brown", "cow"]
>> puts $_
how now brown cow
```

But being mixed in to Object, so it is available at the script level, leaves the problem that every single class ever created ends up having a `#split` method.

If you run plain old split() every object in the system will respond, but fortunately only with an error.

By making it a *private* method, it's available at the top level for scripts (because "Object" is open or something) but doesn't end up part of the API of every single instantiated object.

Comment: some of this went a little over my head, im such a programming noob :(. But I now understand that split is a method for strings not integers, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I got a phone call while I was filling in the explanation a little. I'm not certain I got every aspect of this explanation right; if not I hope someone gives us more details.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing at what you might really want:

```
DATA = 3..8
DATA.each_cons(2) do |a,b|
  puts "#{a} + #{b} = #{a+b}"
end
#=> 3 + 4 = 7
#=> 4 + 5 = 9
#=> 5 + 6 = 11
#=> 6 + 7 = 13
#=> 7 + 8 = 15
```

**Edit**: Based on the desire to operate on successive pairs:

```
DATA = 3..8    # or DATA = [3,4,5,6,7,8]
DATA.each_slice(2) do |a,b|
  puts "#{a} + #{b} = #{a+b}"
end
#=> 3 + 4 = 7
#=> 5 + 6 = 11
#=> 7 + 8 = 15
```

Comment: just working my way through the pickaxe, that is ultimately what I was trying to accomplish but first by pairing the numbers as 34, 56, 78 and then using to_i to get them to add, thanks for your help!

Comment: @yoshyosh See my updated answer above for a far better way to operate on pairs of integers than using a string, splitting and parsing (the currently-accepted answer).